# Algebraic substitutions in order

Tags: replacement, recursion, rule

I have some symbols `xp[m,n]` that satisfy recursion relations, `rule1, rule2, rule3`. I would like to use the relations to reduce the symbols to numbers. But the order of application of the rules matters, so if I apply them in the correct fashion then the reduction succeeds and if I apply them in the wrong fashion then I obtain infinite recursion. Is there a systematic way to only apply them in such a way as to never obtain negative values for the `m, n` in `xp[m,n]`?

For instance,

```
En = 1;
xp[0, 0] = 1;
xp[1, 0] = 0;
xp[0, 1] = 0;
xp[2, 0] = x2;
rule1 = xp[m_, 
    0] -> ((-3 + m) ((-5 + m) (-4 + m) xp[-6 + m, 0] + 
       4 En xp[-4 + m, 0]) - 4 (-2 + m) xp[-2 + m, 0])/(4 (-1 + m));
rule2 = xp[m_, 1] -> I/2 m xp[m - 1, 0];
rule3 = xp[m_, n_] -> (-1 + m) m xp[-2 + m, -2 + n] + 
    2 I m xp[-1 + m, -1 + n] + En xp[m, -2 + n] - xp[2 + m, -2 + n] - 
    xp[4 + m, -2 + n];
```

I can evaluate

```
xp[2, 2] /. rule3 /. rule2 /. rule1 /. rule1
= 1/6.
```

But

```
xp[2,2] /. rule3 /. rule3
=3 - 12 xp[2, -2] - 8 I xp[3, -1] - 31 xp[4, -2] + 
 4 I (2 I + xp[1, -1] - xp[3, -1] - xp[5, -1]) - 12 I xp[5, -1] + 
 2 xp[8, -2] + xp[10, -2]
```

which will not terminate with further rule application because the "wrong" rule has been used and the indices became negative. I would like a strategy to apply the correct sequence of rules automatically, never obtaining negative indices.

Comment: Have you seen [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)?

Comment: Your rule1 makes a step in m of -6. Therefore to be sure that never negative indices appear, you must give stopping condition over 6 steps.  Or for specific starting indices, you must ensure that rule1 is never applied to xp[5,_]